# How can I go about printing a directory tree in a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I want the output to be something like

```
|-------File1 

|-------File2

|-------Folder

       |-------somefile

       |-------Makefile

       |-------Directory

                |-------hi.txt
|-------hello.c
```

I am writing a bash script to obtain this kind of output. I'm having trouble on how to go about this. I want to do this without using the `tree` command.

Answer (score 4):

Don't reinvent the wheel, this is exactly what `tree` command does.

Check `man tree` to get details.

---

All popular distros should have `tree` (installed or) available in their repositories; so if not installed already you can install it using usual manner.

For example, in Debian (and derivatives):

```
sudo apt-get install tree
```

In RPM based distros:

```
sudo yum install tree
```

Comment: Tree is not always installed. So you may need to install it from your repository.

Comment: On OS X `brew install tree` assuming you have homebrew installed